# Setting space within certain elements within a stackview

Tags: ios, swift

Essentially I am trying to create a UIStackView with some elements that has top margins and bottom margins. For example

```
| item one |  
| item two |  
|          |  
| itemfour |
```

I have tried to add a spacerView :

```
let textField1 = UITextField(text: "one")
let textField2 = UITextField(text: "two")
let textField3 = UITextField(text: "four")
let spacerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 100))

viewStack.addSubView(textField1)
viewStack.addSubView(textField2)
viewStack.addSubView(spacerView)
viewStack.addSubView(textField3)
```

However, the height that i am setting the spacerView does not seem to effect the space that is being created in the stack view.

PS: If there is a better way of adding top and bottom margins between two items, I am definitely open to it as adding a UIView feels really hacky

Answer (score 0):

You could:

1. Make a spacer view that's a `UILabel` with `text` of a single space (`" "`). This will give you a blank row that's the same height as the rest of your text. This will work if the distribution is set to `fillEqually` (it works in other modes too, but I mention it because `distribution` matters in option #2 below).

or,

2. Create a subclass of `UIView` and override its `intrinsicContentSize`, returning a `CGSize` that specifies the height you want.  Don't set this view's `frame` (i.e. let the `UIStackView` manage the view's frame). Note that this method only works if the distribution of the `UIStackView` is *not* set to `fillEqually`.